# Which of following is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am confused as to which of the following sentences is correct 
I am sure that first one is correct but I often use the second habitually. I am not sure about correctness of second question format. Please guide.

Did you ask him, yesterday?

You asked him, yesterday?

Comment: Both are fine (without the comma), but the context in which you use them is different.  I would use the first, though, until you are more familiar with "statements used as questions".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a comma in either of those. You can just say, "Did you ask him yesterday?" or, "You asked him yesterday?". The preferred phrasing would be the first one because it offers a better lead into the question.